# Python : Regular expression

Tags: python, regex, strip

I have the following code which does what I want, retrieve the package name from the result of that command :

command :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep amule
```

string to analyze :

```
string = 'amule\t\t\t\t\t\tinstall\namule-common\t\t\t\t\tinstall\namule-utils\t\t\t\t\tinstall\n'
```

code :

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[a-z](.*)\w*(?=([\\\t]*install))")
matches = re.finditer(pattern, result[0])

for match in matches:
    plist.append(match.group().strip())
```

result :

```
plist = ['amule', 'amule-common', 'amule-utils']
```

But I would like to optimize the code, to not use the strip function and obtain the same result only using regex. So far though, I couldn't get rid of all the '\t', even using '+', '*' or {n} before the 'install' string. Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with your help (the backslash was the issue), here's what I could come up with

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([\w\-]+)(?=(\s*install\s*))', re.MULTILINE)
matches = re.finditer(pattern, string_to_analize)

for match in matches:
    print match.group()
```

which does exactly what is needed.

Thanks a lot for your help ! ;)

PS : Just a very strange thing : that regex does not function on the website, do you understand why ? http://regex101.com/r/iM2gJ1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily by using the `re.M` flag (multiline).

`"([\w\-]+)\s*install", re.M`

Like so:

```
match = re.search(r"([\w\-]+)\s*install", re.M)
if match:
    plist = match
```

See a working example here: http://regex101.com/r/jE0dL8

Comment: 2 infos (website and regex) in 1 answer : Thank you !

Comment: Sorry to bother again but actually the code does work on the webiste but not the string coded as in the first post. I tried to modify it using their interface but without any success. The python code I have so far is : p = re.compile(r'([\w\-]+)[\\t]*install[\\n]*', re.MULTILINE)
str = "amule\t\t\t\t\t\tinstall\namule-common\t\t\t\t\tinstall\namule-utils\t\t\t\t\tinstall\n\n"
 
p.match(str) which works on the website but not in my shell. site : http://regex101.com/r/wA4kZ9

Comment: Those \t entities are special character tabs -- escaping them to retrieve literal `\t` (you're using \\t, \\n) is going to cause you problems. Try removing the double backslash?